# How do I set properties with spring?

Tags: spring-mvc

I'm studying spring framework but I'm stuck in properties setting

I try to set some test value with properties but values always default value

here's my code

message.properties

```
name=James
```

applicationContext.xml (also added util files)

```
<util:properties id="msgProperties" location="classpath:config/properties/message.properties"/>
```

code

```
@Component
public class MessageService {
    @Value("#{msgProperties.name}")
    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

it doesn't make any error message and I can run but when I print that name, it always null I think it doesn't wired by some reason I do not know.

I tried @Value("#{msgProperties['name']}") too but result is same.

Do I miss something?

Comment: add your project structure screenshot image

Answer (score 0):

solve it.

since I'm hurrying, I make MessageService instance with new keyword.
get instance by bean factory make it work fine :)